# WPF add a clock to my GUI

Tags: wpf, time, clock

Simple Request - I want to be able to display the current time within my WPF application window. Are there free controls out there for this? Just need to display the time, nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a label or a text block and have its content bound to System.DateTime.Now

Comment: How would that work? DateTime doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged and the time will be displayed only when loading the page.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/digital-clock-in-wpf1